# CSRF verification failed when used csrf_token and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS

Tags: python, html, django, post, csrf

I try to change my profile but when i subbmit my form, it shows CSRF verification failed even when i used csrf_token  and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS.

Here is my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='static/images/default.jpg', upload_to='static/images')
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, authenticated_user):
        profile = cls(user=authenticated_user, name= authenticated_user)
        # do something with the book
        return profile
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My view:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    """Show profile"""
    # profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id= request.user)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method != 'POST':
    # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
    else:
    # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile, data= request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('base:index'))
    context = {'profile': profile}
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

My template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Thong tin nguoi dung:</p>
    <a>Ten nguoi dung: {{profile.name}}</a>
    <p>Anh dai dien: <img src="{{profile.avatar.url}}" alt=""></p>
    <form action="{% url 'users:profile'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
        <p>
            <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="200" required="" id="id_name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="id_avatar">Avatar:</label>
            <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" id="id_avatar">
        </p>
        <button name="submit">save changes</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

My setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static"), ]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://127.0.0.1']
```

How can i sumit my form ?

Comment: Are you testing it in incognito tab?

Comment: please provide your settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to add `type` to button tag because when you set action to form tag then you must add `type` to button tag or input tag.

change this:

```
<button name="submit">save changes</button>
```

To this:

```
 <button type="submit">save changes</button>
```

And see if it solves

Comment: I tried but it's still not wokring.

Comment: i got:  "POST /users/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 403